# Problem with Entity Framework and Lazy Loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 4 and am having a few problems with lazy loading.
I have 3 entities and are each contained in one another.
CarSetup will contain a Car entity who will contain an Event entity. They are all being lazy loaded.

I have created a simplistic unit test to reproduce the problem.

```
CarSetup carSetup = carSetupContext.CreateObject<CarSetup>();
Car car = Load("car1");
carSetup.Car = car;
```

I get a crash when i assign the car to the carsetup object. It actually crashes in the Equals method of the Car entity.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if(obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return this.Event.Equals(((Car)obj).Event);
}
```

If i quickwatch the entity before the equals method gets called, all sub entities get loaded and the problem does not occur.

When i assign the existing car to the car setup, the framework loads all existing CarSetups for that car and calls my "Equals" method with them. However, since lazy loading is enabled, the Event in the Car is null which is normal. When it tries to access the Event property, NO loading happens and it crashes. I have checked the "this" property in the equals method and it is of type "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Car". I also checked and the EventId Guid is correctly set in the car entity.

Anyone have any idea as to what is happening?

EDIT: After doing a bit more testing, if I call my equals method manualy:

```
car.Equals(car);
```

Everything works perfectly. It only happens when the Entity Framework decides to load relationships and automatically calls the Equals method.

Thanks

Comment: There is something wrong with your brackets in return ... of the Equals method. Probably only a typo, since this doesn't even compile and can't be the reason for you problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My entity is a bit more complex so i striped it down for the question didnt really notice the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `Event` isn't being loaded.  From memory I would have done something like this to ensure that the Events are loaded with the Cars:

```
context.Cars.Include("Events");
```

You're using a syntax that I'm not familiar with, but look into the `Include` operator.

Comment: For the syntax, the load part was just an example. If I add the "Include" to my select query, doesn't that defeat the purpose of lazy loading as the whole event will be loading in the initial query? My lazy loading works for the Event if I try to access that property after a load. Its only in that wierd "equals" scenario that it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use POCO objects with enabled DynamicProxies in your object context, right? It might be possible that by casting `obj` to `Car` in your Equals override you cast to your POCO class and not to `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Car` which is dynamically derived from `Car`. With that cast you are effectively stripping off the ability of `obj` (which is probably also of type `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Car` like `this`) to lazily load navigation properties. (Because it's the DynamicProxy which enables lazy loading of POCO entities.)

Now the problem is that you can't cast to `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Car` instead of `Car` since this type doesn't exist at compile time and is only dynamically generated at runtime.

But if you are using C# 4.0 (Visual Studio 2010) you could try to use dynamic typing with the new `dynamic` keyword. Your Equals override would look like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if(obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    dynamic o = obj;

    return this.Event.Equals(o.Event);
}
```

(This all is a shot into the dark and I didn't test anything. But it might be worth a try.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Was worth a shot but I get the same problem. Actually the problem is bigger than this, as both "this" car object and the obj car object passed to the function are both DynamicProxies and both have the Event property null. I've added a comment to my initial post after doing a bit more testing. The scenario only seems to happen when the framework calls my Equals method. It works fine when I call it manually.

Comment: Yes, I was expecting that also `obj` is a DynamicProxy. But then it seems that these proxies don't load the navigation properties when EF calls the Equals method. Hm, I have no idea anymore. Maybe it's a good idea to ask your question again on the MS Dev-Center for EF: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/threads, perhaps with a link to this thread here.